# How can we use multiple Azure web apps with each with different frameworks under one domain name without using sub-domains?

Tags: azure, routes, azure-web-app-service

Example:
our main Azure web app uses ASP.NET, say  www.mywebsite.com.

We want www.mywebsite.com/another_framework to transparently route HTTPS requests to and from an internal, ASP MVC website: www.internalwebsite.com.  When users open www.mywebsite.com/another_framework they see the content for www.internalwebsite.com transparently.

Apache lets us do this with URL rewriting but how is this done in Azure?

We don’t want to rewrite either of the websites and we don’t want to lose the SEO ranking by having multiple sub-domains.

How is this done in Azure with Web Apps?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. What did you investigate yourself? What problems did you encounter?

Comment: are you trying something like virtual directories like domain/

Answer (score 1):

When you publish your Web application into Azure, you also publish your `web.config` file.

In that file you are free to declare your URL rewriting logic.

Take a look at the following articles:

[Azure : Create an URL Rewrite Azure Web App](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32229.azure-create-an-url-rewrite-azure-web-app.aspx)

[Azure App Services: Understanding URL Re-write](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/madhurabharadwaj/2018/06/01/azure-app-services-understanding-url-re-write/)

Comment: Both those links seem to discuss URL 'redirect' more than a transparent (to the client browser) rewrite of the URL.  First link is very complete but not sure it really answers the question.

This looks helpful though ...
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-outbound-rules-for-url-rewrite-module